# Need Rating and ranking Mysql tutorial

Tags: mysql, ranking, rating, rate, voting-system

I would like a simple example tutorial on how to rank user votes

Example: from a table of list of 20 people

I would like for users to be able to vote on several categories of those people
Vote for Best Eyes
Vote for Best Face
Vote for Best Personality

and then rank from 1-20 the table of votes of people with the most votes in Eyes, Face, Personality

I love thenewboston.org mysql tutorials but they only have intermediate tutorials wish they had a voting and ranking tutorial, anyone know of a tutorial lie I have described.

Thanks

Comment: So do you not even have any idea of how you might do this? Have you thought about how your database tables might be structured?

Comment: asking for off-site resources like tutorials are off-topic here

Answer (score 0):

i would say then use [phpmyacademy](https://phpacademy.org/) tutorials. there you can find rating system tutorials or on voting based. here is the direct link also

http://www.onlinevideolecture.com/computer-programming/phpacademy/rating-system/?course_id=2133

search a little on their website. you can find many similar tutorials. hope it helps